# Request and Response objects become undefined when moved to a function (nodejs, express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to separate my routes using the express router however I'm running into an issue. For some reason, when I declare an anonymous function inside my .get method, it works. However, as soon as I define my own function and pass it in, the request and response objects become undefined.

This works

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();

router.get("/", function(request, response, next){
    console.log("getting the hello page");
    response.send("hello");
});

module.exports = router;
```

However this fails

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();

function getHelloPage(request, response, next) {
    console.log("getting the hello page");
    response.send("hello");
}

router.get("/", getHelloPage(request, response, next));

module.exports = router;
```

even tried just having:

```
router.get("/", getHelloPage());
```

Any Ideas of what's going on here?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't call the function when using it as a callback, but rather just use its name so you pass a function reference that can be called later. In your case, you're calling it immediately and passing the return value, and since it doesn't return anything, your original code is equal to:

```
getHelloPage();
router.get("/", undefined);
```

It should work just fine when you pass the function body to it:

```
router.get("/", getHelloPage);
```

---

### TL;DR

It's `getHelloPage` vs. `getHelloPage()` as a callback function.

Comment: I didn't know that about Javascript. Thanks, it now works

Answer (score 0):

What  the express's router expects as second argument is a function to be executed when the route match with the first argument, your getHelloPage function is not returning a function , your function when is executed is not returning nothing, what mean undefined.

What you can do is a function that returns a function with  the expected parameters.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

function getHelloPage(str) {
  return function(request, response, next) {
    console.log('message : ', str);
    response.send(str);
  }
}

router.get('/', getHelloPage('some message'));

module.exports = router;
```

Anyway not make so much sense in this case, but is just a sample.